# Select all button for selecting td tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with each `tr` having `class="ass testPageRow"` I want to be able to all selected the `td` tags. I currently have some code that allows me to select the `td` individually. I am trying to implement a select all button.

```
var testPagesList = document.getElementsByClassName("testPageRow");
for (var i = 0; i < testPagesList.length; i++) {
    var testPageItems = testPagesList[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var j = 0; j < testPageItems.length; j++) {
        testPageItems[j].onclick = function(event) {
            if (this.className == "selected") {
                this.className = "unselected";
            } else {
                this.className = "selected";
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The format of my html

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
  <tr class="ass testPageRow">
    <td id="tp1">1</td>
    <td id="tp4">4</td>
    <td id="tp5">5</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="ass testPageRow">
    <td id="tp12">12</td>
    <td id="tp13">13</td>
    <td id="tp14">14</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="ass testPageRow">
    <td id="tp14TTU">14TTU</td>
    <td id="tp15">15</td>
    <td id="tp16">16</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="ass testPageRow">
    <td id="tp18">18</td>
    <td id="tp20">20</td>
    <td id="tp21">21</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my current javascript code to select the tags. When I click the button, nothing happens. I'm not sure why. My logic was to iterate through all the objects and change the className to `selected` as I did in my previous code.

```
function selectAllTestPages() {
    var selectAllTP = document.getElementById("selectAllTestPages");
    selectAllTP.onclick = function(event) {
        for (var i = 0; i < testPagesList.length; i++) {
            var testPageTDTags = testPagesList[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (var td in testPageTDTags) {
                td.className = "selected";
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Button click:

```
<div class="center">
  <button id="selectAllTestPages">Select All</button>
</div>
```

Comment: so, what's your problem?

Comment: @AmitJoki updated. Sorry. So focused on describing my problem, I forgot to state it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try something like this?

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.testPageRow td')).forEach(function(e) {
    e.className = 'selected';
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/62d4La7w/

Comment: Edit: You need to convert the querySelectorAll result into an array before you can forEach it.

Comment: Did you see my edit? Can you put your code on jsfiddle if it's still having issues? (or modify the link I put up)

Comment: I did not see the jsfiddle let me take a look

Comment: I was wondering how can I push each objects id into and array called testPages?
     `[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.testPageRow td')).forEach(function(e) {
         e.className = 'selected';
         testPages.push(e.attr("id"));

     });`

Comment: `e.attr` doesn't exist as a function in vanilla js. If you're using `jQuery` use `$(e).attr('id')` ... or just use `e.id`

Answer (score 1):

You should really separate the function logic from the event listener logic.

The part of your code that was causing the functionality to break was the `for in` loop that you run on the `testPageTDTags` variable.  You should have been using a regular loop with a counter.

Here's a new version of your code that will do what you are looking for:

```
// Logic to change all tds classes to 'selected'
function selectAllTestPages() {
    var testPagesList = document.getElementsByClassName("testPageRow");
    for (var i = 0; i < testPagesList.length; i++) {
        var testPageTDTags = testPagesList[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var j = 0; j < testPageTDTags.length; j++) {
            testPageTDTags[j].className = "selected";
        }
    }
}

// Event listener that listens for button click
var button = document.getElementById('selectAllTestPages');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    selectAllTestPages();  
});
```

Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2hn7Ljjs/3/) on jsfiddle